# R tools gageRR response input not clear

Tags: r

I am interested in using the gageRR function in one of my projects offered by r tools.

In the following code:

```
gdo = gageRRDesign(3,10, 2, randomize = FALSE)

y = c(23,22,22,22,22,25,23,22,23,22,20,22,22,22,24,25,27,28,23,24,23,24,24,22,
  22,22,24,23,22,24,20,20,25,24,22,24,21,20,21,22,21,22,21,21,24,27,25,27,
      23,22,25,23,23,22,22,23,25,21,24,23)
response(gdo) = y

gdo = gageRR(gdo, tolerance = 5)

summary(gdo)

plot(gdo)
```

How should i organize my data to input to y? There seems to be no explanation for this online.

Ps sorry for not giving proper code format for the code as this option is not available on stackoverflow on my phone.

Comment: The order of y, should match the order the experiment was conducted, which is defined by gdo.

Comment: Please explain, how do you flatten 3 dimensional data to a 1 dimensional list as a value for y?

Comment: It is not 3 dimensional data, it is a table of 3 columns (the number of parameters) and 60 rows long (each experimental run).  The sixty rows are from, in this case, 3 operators, 10 parts at 2 levels each thus 3*10*2.  Print `gdo` from above to see the experimental conditions